# How to create this raster?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, raster, resolution

I have three layers:

1. building data (polygon) attributed with parking lot capacity
2. on the road parking data (line), also contains parking space data
3. car parks (polygon) includes parking space capacity

I would like to create a raster, the raster must be 50 x 50m resolution, in every 50m square I want to know the parking capacity in it, how do I divide my city into pixels and calculate this parking space capacity in the pixels?  I am using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Answer (score 1):

You will need the Spatial Analyst extension installed and licensed. If you do not have this then you will not be able to do the raster calculation. If you do not have the Extension then you could use other software like [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/index.html).

In ArcGIS you would convert your vector data into a raster format using this [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000002v000000), note you can set cell size. Then you would use the [raster calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_Calculator/009z000000z7000000/) to add the rasters together to give you your parking capacity.

Comment: i used raster calcuator but now there is another problem,the raster calculator works on just the intersected pixels and create new raster with just using intersected pixels of each layer